# Is there a way to create EMR security config with CloudFormation/Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, amazon-emr, terraform

I want to archive the logic similar to the CLI command:
aws emr create-security-configuration --name [name] --security-configuration ... and use it further in the Terraform script.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 06/07/2017**: As of [Jun 6 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/aws-cloudformation-now-supports-amazon-emr-security-configurations-aws-lambda-and-aws-x-ray-integration-amazon-cloudwatch-percentile-redshift-resource-tagging-and-other-coverage-updates/), the [`AWS::EMR::SecurityConfiguration`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-securityconfiguration.html) resource is now available in CloudFormation, and as of May 11 2017 (v0.9.5) the [`emr_security_configuration`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_security_configuration.html) resource is available in Terraform.

---

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it is currently possible to specify a [`SecurityConfiguration`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_RunJobFlow.html#EMR-RunJobFlow-request-SecurityConfiguration) for the [`RunJobFlow`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_RunJobFlow.html) API using either CloudFormation's [`AWS::EMR::Cluster`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-cluster.html) CloudFormation Resource or Terraform's [`aws_emr_cluster`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html) resource, and there are no resources that correspond to the [`CreateSecurityConfiguration`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_CreateSecurityConfiguration.html) API.

The [EMR Security Configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-encryption-enable.html) feature was added on [Sep 21 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/09/amazon-emr-now-supports-data-encryption-for-apache-spark-tez-and-hadoop-mapreduce/), and there is typically a lag between new feature announcements and their corresponding support in existing CloudFormation resources.

Although Terraform tends to be updated more quickly as it is an open-source project with a larger development community, the `aws_emr_cluster` resource is still relatively new (released [Oct 6 2016](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#075-october-6-2016)). I've opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11830) tracking a feature request for this implementation.

As a workaround for now, you could create a [Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that calls the `CreateSecurityConfiguration` and `RunJobFlow` APIs directly.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the basic examples here https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html and here https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html.

It would be similar to:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "sg" {
  name = "allow_all"
  description = "Allow all inbound traffic"

  ingress {
      from_port = 0
      to_port = 0
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
      from_port = 0
      to_port = 0
      protocol = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      prefix_list_ids = ["pl-12c4e678"]
  }
}

resource "aws_emr_cluster" "emr-test-cluster" {
  name          = "emr-test-arn"
  release_label = "emr-4.6.0"
  applications  = ["Spark"]

  termination_protection = false
  keep_job_flow_alive_when_no_steps = true

  ec2_attributes {
    subnet_id                         = "${aws_subnet.main.id}"
    emr_managed_master_security_group = "${aws_security_group.sg.id}"
    emr_managed_slave_security_group  = "${aws_security_group.sg.id}"
    instance_profile                  = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.emr_profile.arn}"
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Question is not about security groups.